# Why is there a slight delay in the color change in my animation?

Tags: html, css-animations

If you pay close attention to the animation, you can notice there's a slight pause in the colour transition and I want something smoother. I'm currently starting out and I'm finding it difficult to figure out why that's the case. Can someone help me figure that out and provide a possible fix?

```css
            .intro {
                font-family: 'Playfair Display';
                font-size: 49px;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                line-height: 0.9;
                margin-top: 260px;
                margin-left: 30px;

            }
            #intro-text {
                animation-name: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 5s;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-delay: 0s; 
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                cursor: default;
                transition: color 0.7s ease-in-out;
            }

            @keyframes changeColor{
            0% {
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                opacity: 0.2;
            }

            25% {
                color: rgb(150, 131, 131);
                opacity: 0.4;
            }

            50% {
                color: rgb(140, 131, 131);
                opacity: 0.6;
            }

            75% {
                color: rgb(130, 121, 121,);
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            100% {
                color: rgb(100, 091, 091);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;      0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon2.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Why</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="intro">
                <span id="intro-text">Hello! I'm an AI.</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slight pauses are due to the keyframes-selector of 25%, 50% and 75%. Keeping only the 0% and 100% selectors will result in a smooth animation.

```css
            .intro {
                font-family: 'Playfair Display';
                font-size: 49px;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                line-height: 0.9;
                margin-top: 260px;
                margin-left: 30px;

            }
            #intro-text {
                animation-name: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 5s;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-delay: 0s; 
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                cursor: default;
                transition: color 0.7s ease-in-out;
            }

            @keyframes changeColor{
            0% {
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                opacity: 0.2;
            }

            100% {
                color: rgb(100, 091, 091);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;      0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon2.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Why</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="intro">
                <span id="intro-text">Hello! I'm an AI.</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center {
      
      margin: 0 auto;
      
    }

    .awesome {
      
      font-family: futura;
      font-style: italic;
      
      width:100%;
      
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      
      color:#313131;
      font-size:45px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-animation:colorchange 20s infinite alternate;
      
      
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes colorchange {
      0% {
        
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
       opacity: 0.2;

      }
      
      10% {
        
        color: #8e44ad;
      }
      
      20% {
        
        color: #1abc9c;
      }
      
      30% {
        
        color: #d35400;
      }
      
      40% {
        
        color: blue;
      }
      
      50% {
        
        color: #34495e;
      }
      
      60% {
        
        color: blue;
      }
      
      70% {
        
        color: #2980b9;
      }
      80% {
     
        color: #f1c40f;
      }
      
      90% {
     
        color: #2980b9;
      }
      
      100% {
        
        color: pink;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class='center'>

  <p class="awesome">Hello! I'm an AI.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the timing function set to `ease-in-out` the amimation run slowly both at the beginning and the end.
For speed up the initial phase (0%) you can set opacity starting from 0.4 (or more).